# External GNU BinUtils "Sort" by column won't work in VIM

Tags: bash, sorting, vim, binutils

I have a simple table of data in VIM consisting of two sets of variable-length strings. For example:

```
test bob
check mike
review tom
test2 tom
presentation mike
```

I have been able to make it "prettier" by piping it through `column`, by selecting all five lines in VIM using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, selecting all five entire lines visually, then hitting the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd> key combination to enter command mode, and then issue the command `'<,'>!column -t`, which makes it look like:

```
test          bob
check         mike
review        tom
test2         tom
presentation  mike
```

Now, I would like to finally sort by the **second** column. I tried doing a visual block selection, and using `'<,'>!sort -n -k2`, but I just get:

```
check         mike
presentation  mike
review        tom
test          bob
test2         tom
```

So, it sorts, but only by the first column. Thinking this uses perhaps the literal column number rather than assuming <kbd>SPACE</kbd> as a delimiter, and accounting for consecutive delimiters, I tried again with `'<,'>!sort -n -k15`, but I still get the same undesired behavior.

How can I get this to sort by the second column, either by the literal column number (ie: 15), or by the visual column number (ie: 2)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this command:

```
%sor r /\S\+$/
```

generates:

```
test          bob
check         mike
presentation  mike
review        tom
test2         tom
```

check `:h :sort` for details

your block-wise visual selection won't help sorting (either built-in or external). because it passed a `range`, which is line based, even though the selection looks in block/column wise. `:h range` for detail. If you want to use  external sort, you should do exactly same as in shell.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to somehow apply this logic to a visual block?

Comment: It works in block selection mode too. Please disregard my above comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the separator like this:

`'<,'>!sort -t' ' -k2`

(**not that there is no -n flag**)

From the manual (`man sort`):

`-t, --field-separator=SEP
              use SEP instead of non-blank to blank transition`

For me it makes:

```
check         mike
presentation  mike
review        tom
test2         tom
test          bob
```

Become:

```
test          bob
presentation  mike
check         mike
review        tom
test2         tom
```

Comment: I tried this, but it sorts the same way as in my original question.

Comment: @Dogbert, edited answer for my output, maybe it will works for others.
Please check if this works for you and give your input

Comment: I don't get the same output as you. I'm going to attribute it to some bizarre behavior on my machine (ie: mix of MacPorts and standard OSX BinUtils). Thank you.

Comment: So it's a partial solution, still best to leave it here. I usually delete my wrong answers but this works for me and I'm running a standard Ubuntu installation with practically nothing exceptional on.